# About Reusing UITouch and UIEvent Object

Tags: ios, swift, uitouch, uievent

I'm trying to understand `UIEvent`, `UITouch` Object reusing So I trying test but result makes me confused

this is my code

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("==========================")
        print("Event Object : \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(event!).toOpaque())")
        for (index, touch) in touches.enumerated() {
            print("\(index)'s, UITouch Object : \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(touch).toOpaque())")
        }
        print("==========================")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var skyBlueView: CustomView!
    var previousTouch:UITouch?
    var currentTouch:UITouch?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("==========================")
        print("Event Object : \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(event!).toOpaque())")
        for (index, touch) in touches.enumerated() {
            print("\(index)'s, UITouch Object : \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(touch).toOpaque()) Tap Count: \(touch.tapCount)")
        }
        print("==========================")
    }
}
```

I expect that touch objects of same coordinates are same

but result wasn't. This are[image] my results

Here is my questions

1. When UIEvent Object is released? UIEvent is still reused
2. Tap counts are increasing on same coordinates, but objects are different 
   how Tap counts is shared between UITouch Objects
3. 9 touches occurred but only 4 UITouch objects (0x00007f9881c086f0, 0x00007f9881d04000, 0x00007f9881e02650, 0x00007f988500c5c0) are reusing? how does it works?